# Does the following minimum exist?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

Let $g \in L^{p}(\Omega ; \mathbb{R}^n)$ , $p>1$ and $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n $ an open and bounded set with smooth boundary and consider the following functional:$$W_{0}^{1,p}\left(\Omega ; \mathbb{R} \right)\ni u\mapsto J\left(u\right):=\int_{\Omega}\left|\nabla u-g\right|^{p}\mathrm{d}x.$$
Does this functional has a minimum? And if yes, what is the Euler-Lagrange equation?

Comment: I would doubt that a minimizer exists, since the functional is not convex in $\nabla u$. (However, in the case $n = 1$ the minimum should be zero and is obtained).

Comment: With $|\nabla u - g|^p$ this would make more sense, especially since you say that $g$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is the formula for $J$ correct?

Comment: Thank you, it was a typo, indeed.

Comment: As far as the E-L equations are concerned: $\operatorname{div}(|\nabla u -
 g|^{p-2}(\nabla u - g)) = 0$ (for $g \equiv 0$ you obtain the familiar p-Laplace operator, but the derivation is the same).

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz : Thanks . I also deduced E-L equation , but the existence of the minimum is what  I find difficult to prove.